# ASP MVC 5 Custom Validation Attribute to Compare Two Properties?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, customvalidator, validationattribute

I have the following custom validation attribute to check if two properties are not the same but its applied to the entire model:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]
public class ValidateUser : ValidationAttribute
{
    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        UserViewModel user = value as UserViewModel;
        if(user.UserId == user.ManagerId)
        {
            ErrorMessage = "The user and manager cannot be the same";
            return false;
        }
        return true;

    }
}

[ValidateUser]
public class UserViewModel
{
   [DisplayName("Request By")]
   public string UserId { get; set; }

   [DisplayName("Assign To")]
   public string ManagerId { get; set; }
}
```

How can I create a validation attribute so that instead having to decoarate the entire view model I can decorate the properties that need validating so that the error message appears close to the field being validated. something like below:

```
   [DisplayName("Request By")]
   [ValidateUser]
   public string UserId { get; set; }

   [DisplayName("Assign To")]
   [ValidateUser]
   public string ManagerId { get; set; }
```

Comment: you'd have to use reflection.  Personally I don't think DataAnnotationAttributes should extend outside the scope of a single property.  You can have a validation routine on the model/viewmodel for such things.  But that's just me.

Comment: Consider using a [foolproof](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/) `[NotEqualTo]` validation attribute applied to your properties. Other wise you can create you own - refer [The Complete Guide To Validation In ASP.NET MVC 3 - Part 2](http://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/the-complete-guide-to-validation-in-asp.net-mvc-3-part-2) for a good guide

Answer (score -2):

There is another possible way to validate Properties values is to use `Remote` attribute

***In your Model class***

```
 [DisplayName("Request By")]
 public string UserId { get; set; }


 [DisplayName("Assign To")]
 [Remote("Validate","Home", HttpMethod="Post", AdditionalFields="UserId", ErrorMessage = "Should not be same")]
       public string ManagerId { get; set; }
```

***In your controller***

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Validate(string ManagerId , string UserId )
{
  // put some validation involving ManagerId and UserId here
  return Json(true);
}
```

<kbd>[Working Demo is here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/59L3Ca)</kbd>